# how to get Id of the anchor tag from where the js method got called LWC

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I'm trying to access the id assigned to the  tag where where I'm calling the js method.

```
<ul>
                    <template for:each={errorList} for:item='objError'>
                        <li key={objError.Id}>
                            <a id={objError.Id} type={objError.type} class="slds-text-link_reset" onclick={handleErrorClick}>
                            <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:jump_to_bottom" size="xx-small" class="slds-p-right_small" alternative-text={objError.error}></lightning-icon>
                            {objError.error}
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </template>
                </ul>
```

JS :

```
handleErrorClick(event){
        /* eslint-disable no-console */
        console.log('event : ' ,event.target.Id);
}
```

How can I get the value held in the Id attribute.

Comment: You should never reference an id, as they are changed by the framework

Answer (score 2):

You did not shared what is not working - but my guess is that you don`t get a value?

1. the attribute is called id - not Id
2. lighnting-icon is a child of your link and can therefore be the event target - but it has no id attribute
3. Salesforce recommends to not use id atrributes as they are modified by the framework (and i guess you want to use it to lookup the item in your list) - you should you use an alternative like a data attribute

Here is an example which uses a data attribute and css in order to prevent fireing the event from the lightning-icon element:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/TDY87YRRd/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Id in LWC as they are modified at runtime by framework. Instead use some other attributes (preferably data- attributes) for identification.

Here is the detailed explanation:
https://salesforcesas.home.blog/2019/07/16/lwc-selectors-identification-of-elements/